# GANs for image translation

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, gan

I am training a generative adversarial network to perform style transfer from two different image domains (source `S` and target `T`). Since I have available class information I have an extra `Q` network (except `G` and `D`) that measures the classification results of the generated images for the target domain and their labels (a LeNet network). From the convergence of the system I have noticed that `D` is starting always from 8 (the loss function error of the `D` network) and slightly drops until 4.5 and the `G` loss function error is starting from 1 and quickly drops to 0.2. Is that behavior an example of mode-collapse? What is exactly the relationship between the errors of `D` and `G`? The loss function of `D` and `G` I am using can be found here https://github.com/r0nn13/conditional-dcgan-keras while the loss function of `Q` network is categorical cross-entropy. Is the behavior of `D` and `G` normal? Why `D` loss function is always high?

Loss function:

[image]